# Django access fields of model with many to many relationship

Tags: django, many-to-many, field

So I have the following models:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='postimages')
    id=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    id=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    images=models.ManyToManyField(Image)
    user=models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='posts')
```

In my views I have created a post object like this:

```
post=Post(title=title)
post.save()
post.images.add(image)
```

Now I need to diplay the image field of the Image model in my homepage. I am trying to do it like this:

```
{%for post in posts%}
    <img src="{{post.images.image}}">
{%endfor%}
```

But this returns image with src=(unknown). So my question is how do I access the image field of the Image model?

EDIT:
Here is my views.py

```
def addpost(request):
    imageform=ImageForm()
    postform=PostForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        imageform=ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        postform=PostForm(request.POST)
        if imageform.is_valid() and postform.is_valid():
            #add the image and the post to the database
            image=Image(image=request.FILES['image'])
            image.save()
            title=request.POST['title']
            post=Post(title=title)
            post.save()
            post.images.add(image)
    return redirect('../')
```

And my form:

```
    <form method="post" action="{%url 'addpost'%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{imageform}}
        {{postform}}
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: src=(unknown) or src=" "?

Comment: Well when I inspect my page in the html there is <img src(unknown)>

Comment: Can you show us full rendering function in views.py Is there data in your database about image. I mean is your views.py working

Comment: I added my views.py and my home.html in the post. How do I check if the views.py is working? When I do print(Image.objects.all()) I get a QuerySet so I am assuming it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it. In my html I was calling {{post.images.image}}. Instead I need to call {{post.images.all}} to get all image models and then for every single one I need to get the image. So instead of

```
{%for post in posts%}
    <img src="{{post.images.image}}">
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

I need to do

```
{%for post in posts%}
    {%for image in post.images.all%}
        <img src="{{image.image}}">
    {%endfor%}
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
{%endfor%}
```